# Is there a way to handle this error when updating a record in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So this is my web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\BookingController;
use App\Http\Controllers\BookingRoomController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController;
use App\Http\Controllers\GuestController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RoomController;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Room;
use App\Models\Guest;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome',[
        'customerCount' => Customer::count(),
        'guestCount' => Guest::count(),
        'roomCount' => Room::count()
        ]);
});
// Customer Controller
Route::get('/customers',[CustomerController::class,'index'])->name('customers.index');    

Route::get('/customers/add',[CustomerController::class,'create'])->name('customers.create');

Route::post('/customers',[CustomerController::class,'store'])->name('customers.store');

Route::post('/customers/update',[CustomerController::class,'update'])->name('customers.update');

Route::get('/customers/search',[CustomerController::class,'search'])->name('customers.search');

Route::get('/customers/{id}',[CustomerController::class,'show'])->name('customers.show');   

Route::delete('/customers/{id}',[CustomerController::class,'destroy'])->name('customers.destroy');

// Guest Controller

Route::get('/guests',[GuestController::class,'index'])->name('guests.index');

Route::get('/guests/add',[GuestController::class,'create'])->name('guests.create');

Route::post('/guests',[GuestController::class,'store'])->name('guests.store');

Route::post('/guests/update',[GuestController::class,'update'])->name('guests.update');

Route::get('/guests/search',[GuestController::class,'search'])->name('guests.search');

Route::get('/guests/{id}',[GuestController::class,'show'])->name('guests.show');

Route::delete('/guests/{id}',[GuestController::class,'destroy'])->name('guests.destroy');

// Rooms

Route::get('/rooms',[RoomController::class,'index'])->name('rooms.index');

Route::post('/rooms/update',[RoomController::class,'update'])->name('rooms.update');

Route::get('/rooms/{id}',[RoomController::class,'show'])->name('rooms.show');

// Bookings
Route::get('/bookings',[BookingController::class,'index'])->name('bookings.index');

Route::get('/bookings/create',[BookingController::class,'create'])->name('bookings.create');

Route::post('/bookings',[BookingController::class,'store'])->name('bookings.store');

Route::get('/bookings/{id}',[BookingController::class,'show'])->name('bookings.show');

// Booking Rooms

Route::post('/bookingrooms',[BookingRoomController::class,'store'])->name('bookingrooms.store');

// Authentication

Auth::routes();


Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

// Route::get('/email/verify', function () {
//     return view('auth.verify-email');
// })->middleware('auth')->name('verification.notice');

// Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
//     $request->fulfill();

//     return redirect('/home');
// })->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verification.verify');
```

This is my customer controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Customer;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['store','create']);
    }


    public function index(){

        $customer = Customer::latest()->get();

        return view('customers.index',['customer' => $customer]);
    }

    public function show($id){
       $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);

       return view('customers.show',['customer' => $customer]);
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('customers.create');
    }

    public function store(){
        $customer = new Customer();
        
        $customer->title = request('title');
        $customer->first_name = request('firstname');
        $customer->last_name = request('lastname');
        $customer->date_of_birth = request('dateofbirth');
        $customer->street = request('street');
        $customer->town = request('town');
        $customer->province = request('province');
        $customer->postal_code = request('postalcode');
        $customer->home_phone = request('homephone');
        $customer->work_phone = request('workphone');
        $customer->mobile_phone = request('mobilephone');
        $customer->email = request('email');

        $customer->save();

        return redirect('/')->with('mssg','Added customer successfully!');
    }

    public function update(Request $req){

        $customer = Customer::findorFail($req->id);

        $customer->title = $req->title;
        $customer->first_name = $req->firstname;
        $customer->last_name = $req->lastname;
        $customer->date_of_birth = $req->dateofbirth;
        $customer->street = $req->street;
        $customer->town = $req->town;
        $customer->province = $req->province;
        $customer->postal_code = $req->postalcode;
        $customer->home_phone = $req->homephone;
        $customer->work_phone = $req->workphone;
        $customer->mobile_phone = $req->mobilephone;
        $customer->email = $req->email;

        $customer->save();

        return redirect('/')->with('mssg','Updated customer successfully!');

    }

    public function search(Request $req){

        $search = $req->get('search-customer');

        $customer = Customer::where('first_name','like','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);
               
        return view('customers.index',['customer' => $customer]);
 //     $records = ['first_name' => '%'.$search.'%',
    //     'title' => '%'.$search.'%',
    //     'last_name' => '%'.$search.'%'
    // ];
    }

    public function destroy($id){
        $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);

        $customer->delete();

        return redirect('/')->with('mssg','Customer has been deleted!');

    }
    public function quantity(){
        $customer = Customer::all();

        return view('/',['customers' => $customer]);
    }

}
```

This is my show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="insert-customer-container-main">
    <h1>Customer Information</h1>
    <p>Please fill in the following</p>
    <form class="insert-customer-container" action="{{ route('customers.update') }}"  method="POST">
        @csrf
        {{-- get in controller to manipulate updating --}}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$customer->id}}">
        <div class="customer-input-container row-one">
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="title">Title</label><br/>
                <input style="width:945px" type="text" name="title" value="{{$customer->title}}" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="customer-input-container row-two">
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{$customer->first_name}}">
            </div>
        
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" value="{{$customer->last_name}}">
            </div>
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth</label><br/>
                <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" value="{{$customer->date_of_birth}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="customer-input-container row-three">
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="street">Street</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="street" value="{{$customer->street}}">
            </div>
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="town">Town</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="town" value="{{$customer->town}}">
            </div>
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="province">Province</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="province" value="{{$customer->province}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="customer-input-container row-four">
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="homephone">Home Phone</label><br/>
                <input type="number" name="homephone" value="{{$customer->home_phone}}">
            </div>
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="workphone">Work Phone</label><br/>
                <input type="number" name="workphone" value="{{$customer->work_phone}}">
            </div>
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="mobilephone">Mobile Phone</label><br/>
                <input type="number" name="mobilephone" value="{{$customer->mobile_phone}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="customer-input-container row-five">
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="postalcode">Postal Code</label><br/>
                <input  type="number" name="postalcode" value="{{$customer->postal_code}}">
            </div>
            <div class="customer-input">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label><br/>
                <input style="width:50vw;" type="email" name="email" value="{{$customer->email}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
    <form class="delete-form" action={{ route('customers.destroy', $customer->customer_id) }} method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <input type="submit" class="submit delete-btn" value="Delete">
    </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

**So my question is**

1. When I'm editing a specific record and when I submit it, it redirects me to 404 page which is not what I'm expecting. Is there a way to fix this problem? I'm new in laravel and hoping someone could help. Thanks everyone!

Comment: which version you use

Comment: it's the latest one sir. laravel 8

Comment: does the  data is updated?

Comment: no sir, it's not even updating. it just redirects me to 404 page

Comment: Okay then the issue is with the routes

Comment: how can i fix it sir? please help I'm stuck

Comment: change your route to PUT (for update route) method and remove the /update  hope it will work

Comment: you can simply use `Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');` to use crud it will reduce your code by 1/4

Comment: does this mean that i should delete the whole routes for customer and replace it with one line?

Answer (score 0):

> May be your Route wrong

```
Route::get('/customers',[CustomerController::class,'index'])->name('customers.index');    

Route::get('/customers/add',[CustomerController::class,'create'])->name('customers.create');

Route::post('/customers',[CustomerController::class,'store'])->name('customers.store');

Route::post('/customers/update',[CustomerController::class,'update'])->name('customers.update');

Route::get('/customers/search',[CustomerController::class,'search'])->name('customers.search');

Route::get('/customers/{id}',[CustomerController::class,'show'])->name('customers.show');   

Route::delete('/customers/{id}',[CustomerController::class,'destroy'])->name('customers.destroy');
```

> after

```
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');
```

> edit your all routes by resource after that try and also check your
> route list

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: after checking for the route list sir what should I do? sorry I'm new in laravel

Answer (score 0):

404: Not found

I think that is due to the wrong url you have passed as an action.

try to clean up your routes:

`Route::group(['prefix' => 'customers', 'as' => 'customers.'], function() { Route::post('/update',[CustomerController::class,'update'])->name('customers.update'); });`